# Vim: How do I tell where a function is defined? (

Tags: latex, vim, macvim

I just installed [macvim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) yesterday and I installed [vim latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download) today.

One of the menu items is calling a broken function (`TeX-Suite -> view`).

When I click on the menu-time it makes this call:

```
:silent! call Tex_ViewLatex()
```

**Question: Where can I find that function?  Is there some way to figure out where it is defined?**

---

Just for curiosity sake I removed the silent part and ran this:

```
:call Tex_ViewLatex()
```

Which produces:

```
Error detected while processing function Tex_ViewLaTeX:
line   34:
E121: Undefined variable: s:viewer
E116: Invalid arguments for function strlen(s:viewer)
E15: Invalid expression: strlen(s:viewer)
line   39:
E121: Undefined variable: appOpt
E15: Invalid expression: 'open '.appOpt.s:viewer.' $*.'.s:target
line   79:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
E116: Invalid arguments for function substitute(execString, '\V$*', mainfname, 'g'
)
E15: Invalid expression: substitute(execString, '\V$*', mainfname, 'g')
line   80:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
E116: Invalid arguments for function Tex_Debug
line   82:
E121: Undefined variable: execString
E15: Invalid expression: 'silent! !'.execString
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I suspect that if I could see the source function I could figure out what inputs are bad or what it is looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `:verbose` prefix command:

```
:verbose function Tex_ViewLaTeX
```

In the second line of output (just above the function's body) is the location of where the function was defined.

Answer (score 0):

I installed gVim 7.2 on windows and latex-suite, and miktex too
I tried what you said, after compile and view, I can view the dvi files

The error message seemed like to indicate it's the view's problem

The document for latex-suite said the viewer for Macintosh is not set, maybe it's where the problem lies

I think you can try to set a few variables in your .vimrc file, to set up the proper viewing app for PDF files

And the source code for Tex_ViewLaTeX is here:
http://www.tedpavlic.com/research_related/tpavlic_masters_thesis/compiler.vim

By the way, I also installed MacVim on my Macbook Pro, however I never used vim for LaTeXing, because I find TextMate and its latex bundle is much superior than MacVim, you'll definately like it

Answer (score 0):

One way to search would be to do a grep or vimgrep on directory tree where you thought the source file was located.  Search for 'function Tex_ViewLatex' or 'function! Tex_ViewLatex'.

I believe in the usual install it would be in a .../ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim file, as part of the latex-suite plugin.  There are a couple ftplugin directories, so make sure you get right one (one is in tree of main vim install and other may be off your home .vim directory.

It seems there is a bug with the Tex_ViewLatex function on OS X.  Check here for some info:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.editors.vim.latex.devel/775

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .vimrc, solved the problem for me.

let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'open -a Preview.app'